# Warning: Assigning to 'NSError *__strong **' from 'NSError *__autoreleasing **'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have inherited the below code as part of the XMLReader class. Nothing at SO seems to explain how to get rid of the warning on the line:

```
Assigning to 'NSError *__strong **' from 'NSError *__autoreleasing **' discard qualifiers in nested pointer types

_errorPointer = &error;
```

Appreciate your help.

```
#pragma mark Parsing

- (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _errorPointer = &error;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the same reader, but this https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader looks like a version that plays well with ARC. - In your code, taking the address of a method parameter looks like a bad idea.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much. Don't understand why I did not try to find it myself. Thanks again.